# Grails Calendar plugin issue - string 'struct' in value field

Tags: grails, datepicker, calendar, grails-2.0

I am trying to use Grails Calendar plugin - https://grails.org/plugin/calendar for getting a date picker. The way I am using this is

```
<calendar:resources/> 
<calendar:datePicker name="startDate" value="${prePopulatedValue}" dateFormat="%Y-%m-%d"/>
```

Calendar is rendered properly but when I submit the form, the value for field startDate is 'struct'

When I check the rendered html code, there is a hidden field for startDate with value 'struct' and the correct value is under field 'startDate_value'

```
<input type="hidden" name="startDate" id="startDate" value="struct">
<input type="text" id="startDate_value" name="startDate_value" readonly="true">
```

Now in my code I have placed this calender code in a template and its value is being used in javascript at lot of places.
I am using this code while trying to upgrade my Grails application and not writing it from stratch. So updating all the javascript code and appending "_value" involves lot of work.

In older version of my Grails application, calendar was rendered using YUI which now has issues, so I am trying calendar plugin.

Is this (getting 'struct' as the value) an issue with Grails calendar plugin ? Is there any workaround ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

don't know if it would of some help for you...
I have a small taglib for a datepicker, which in turn, uses the jquery datepicker and have - of course - also a hidden DateField with a struct value. It needs - beside of that - also fields for day, month and year to work seamlessly with grails.

I use my taglib in some of my projects (grails 2.x.x projects) without changing the grails-logik etc. Works seamlessly.

You need - of course - the jquery + datepicker javascripts in your page...

If it might help, here's the url: [jquery-datepicker-taglib](https://github.com/susannej/grails-jquery-datepicker)

It was once a quick hack, and my first taglib, because of that it might not be as nice coded as you would expect, but since than, it works in a lot of use-cases... :-)

...

I don't know the plugin you mentioned, but in general, the grails 2.x date-field consists of 4 fields:

```
<input type="hidden" name="reDat" id="reDat" value="date.struct" />
<input type="hidden" name="reDat_day" id="reDat_day" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="reDat_month" id="reDat_month" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="reDat_year" id="reDat_year" value="" />
```

normaly not of type hidden.

But in my case, I have an additional field for the datepicker and populate after changing the date the grails-fields for the date, that the rest of grails can go working without any other/additional action taken...